# Get Css Computed Styles with Java Script But Exclude Browser Default Styles

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to get some specific style of an element with getComputedStyle method (or any other way) and Ignore browser default style?

e.g: there is an element that I didn't set background color but when I get Computed style, it return rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) background-color which is default browser style and I don't want it.

Comment: what is a browser default style?

Comment: if you mean Default CSS Values for HTML Elements, these you can not exclude, these can be overwritten

Comment: yes, I mean that. Thank you

Comment: What would you want instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025329/how-to-get-the-applied-style-from-an-element-excluding-the-default-user-agent-s

reference link